# reaching each cell in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data frame like below:

```
data = {"Location" : ["one","one","two","one","three","two","three"], "Barcode" : [121,234,121,121,234,543,543], "A" : [1,3,2,0,5,0,3], "B" : [0,3,2,1,5,0,0], "C" : [0,0,2,1,5,4,6], "D" : [3,2,0,3,0,1,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: df]

what I want to do is to iterate over rows and columns(from A to the end) and check whether each cell is over zero or not?

I tried to use df.iteritems() but did not get any answer.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `iteritems()`

for instance:

```
for (columnName, columnData) in empDfObj.iteritems():
   print('Colunm Name : ', columnName)
   print('Column Contents : ', columnData.values)
```

will result

```
Colunm Name :  Name
Column Contents :  ['jack' 'Riti' 'Aadi' 'Mohit']
Colunm Name :  Age
Column Contents :  [34 31 16 32]
Colunm Name :  City
Column Contents :  ['Sydney' 'Delhi' 'New York' 'Delhi']
```